# Emulate free drawing with fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am developing application which has whiteboard. Whiteboard should work like idroo.com. One user is drawing something another user should be able to see it on his browser in real time. I use fabricjs as canvas wrapper and it has everithing I need. But I can't emulate free drawing on canvas. I send mouse position and brush options to remote client and try to render them by firing mouse move events. But it don't work. If some body has simialiar problem can you please help?

```
canvasContainer.on('mousemove', function (e) {      
    var left = canvasContainer.offset().left;
    var top = canvasContainer.offset().top;
    var x = e.pageX - left;
    var y = e.pageY - top;         
    //Send data to remote browser by socket.io or signalr
    //I need to draw on remote browser by these x and y coordinates.
    updateCursor(_connections, x, y);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the event from mouse move and then using canvas.trigger to fire the event on the target canvas?

Comment: yes. I tried it. But I can't serialize event object to json to send it.

Comment: What goes wrong during serialization?

Comment: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON. But event if I serialize it how can I trigger event in another browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var brush = new fabric.PencilBrush(canvas);
var points = [[10,10], [20,20], [25,70],[100,300]];

brush.onMouseDown({x:points[0][0], y:points[0][1]});
for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++) {
  brush.onMouseMove({x:points[i][0], y:points[i][1]});
}
```

See plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/V1c1xkB29tgB2ha99CRQ?p=preview

You can simplify your code for calculating x and coordinates and do it like this:

```
var point = canvas.getPointer(e);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will try and let you know.

Comment: It would probably make sense to call brush.onMouseUp(x,y) as well. So I guess you should just send the type of event (mousedown, mousemove, mouseup) along with x & y coordinates to your socket.io clients and call corresponding methods from `brush`.

Comment: Yes it works. But it begin to come slow after 10-20 sec of drawing. And monitor performance show cpu consumption... Do you know why?

Comment: It's hard to guess not seeing the code. Does the number of points in the rendered path affect the performance? Or it just happens after 10-20 seconds no matter how complex the path is?

Comment: Awesome :-) Good luck with this project.